# Returning separate text within same class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using BS4 to return information off the following page: https://www.sportsbookreview.com/betting-odds/mlb-baseball/money-line/?date=20171029

The issue I have is surrounding returning the by-inning score box into a usable format.  Ideally I would like to save a list of scores by half-inning which would look like ['3','0','0','0'...].  So far I am only able to return ['30','00'...].

Both scores are within the same class which I believe is causing the issue:

```
<div class="_2563p">
<div class="_1Y3rN _308Yc">
<div>3</div>
<div>0</div></div>
<div class="_1Y3rN _308Yc">
<div>0</div>
<div>0</div>
</div>
```

I can currently return the group scores ['30','00'...] using the following:

```
import bs4, pandas as pd, re
from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver  
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException  
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\grant\PythonScripts\chromedriver.exe') 
url = ('https://www.sportsbookreview.com/betting-odds/mlb-baseball/?date=' + betDate) # Full MLs
driver.get(url)
fullML = driver.page_source
driver.quit()

fullMLsoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(fullML, 'html.parser')

x = [el.text.strip() for el in fullMLsoup.find_all(re.compile(r'div'), {'class':"_1Y3rN _308Yc"})]
print(x)
```

Could someone help return in the ['3','0','0','0'] format I am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can use nth child and first-child with bs4 4.7.1. That gets up to last two columns.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.sportsbookreview.com/betting-odds/mlb-baseball/money-line/?date=20171029')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
top = [item.text for item in soup.select('._308Yc div:first-child')]
bottom = [item.text for item in soup.select('._308Yc div:nth-child(2)')]
print(top, bottom)
```

---

You can get everything as json by regex and then parse json. Explore json [here](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=39a01ca894f74b4cb1fe71023a5a2c0e)

```
import requests
import re
import json
r = requests.get('https://www.sportsbookreview.com/betting-odds/mlb-baseball/money-line/?date=20171029')
p = re.compile(r'window.__INITIAL_STATE__=(.*?);\n', re.DOTALL)
data = json.loads(p.findall(r.text)[0])
```

Comment: Could you please explain by json i am trying to find values 3,0,0,1 but not able to find.